# How to prevent $_SESSION from passing variable to another form even if the value doesn't exist in mysql?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, session

I have two forms. The first form has two inputs: date and id. The id should be in the database otherwise, it will not save. What the $_SESSION does is that it passes the value from ID when I submit the form to the second form which is in the same page too. **How can I prevent this from passing the value if the user has put a value that is not in the database?** My php code issues a modal which says that the ID the the user has put is invalid however, it still passes to the other form...

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
    include 'config.php';

    if (isset($_POST['documentRequest1']))
    {

        $chkbox = $_POST['docs'];
        $id = $_POST['a'];

        $totalPrice = 0;
        $total_cedula = 0;
        $isPartOfTotal = 0;


         foreach($chkbox as $chk1)  
           { 
                    if($chk1=='Certificate of Residency') 
                    {
                      $chek_val=$_POST['d1'];
                      $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT price FROM document WHERE typeOfDoc = '$chk1';");
                      $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);                               
                      $isPartOfTotal = $chek_val * $row["price"];
                      $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT into requestitem (DocumentRequest_idDocumentRequest, Document_idDocument, quantity, isPartOfTotal, price, paymentStatus) VALUES ((SELECT idDocumentRequest FROM documentrequest WHERE Person_idPerson = '$id'), (SELECT idDocument FROM document WHERE typeOfDoc = '$chk1'), '$chek_val', '$isPartOfTotal',' $total_cedula', 'Unpaid');");
                    }
                    else if($chk1=='Barangay Clearance') 
                    {
                      $chek_val=$_POST['d2'];
                      $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT price FROM document WHERE typeOfDoc = '$chk1';");
                      $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);                               
                      $isPartOfTotal = $chek_val * $row["price"];
                      $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT into requestitem (DocumentRequest_idDocumentRequest, Document_idDocument, quantity, isPartOfTotal, price, paymentStatus) VALUES ((SELECT idDocumentRequest FROM documentrequest WHERE Person_idPerson = '$id'), (SELECT idDocument FROM document WHERE typeOfDoc = '$chk1'), '$chek_val', '$isPartOfTotal',' $total_cedula', 'Unpaid');");
                    } 
                    else if ($chk1=='Cedula')
                    {
                      $chek_val=$_POST['d3'];
                      //$income=$_POST['income'];
                      $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT income FROM person WHERE idPerson = '$id';");
                      $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                      $income = $row['income'];
                      $total_cedula = ($income * 12 * .001) + 5;

                      $isPartOfTotal = $chek_val * $total_cedula;
                      $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT into requestitem (DocumentRequest_idDocumentRequest, Document_idDocument, quantity, isPartOfTotal, price, paymentStatus) VALUES ((SELECT idDocumentRequest FROM documentrequest WHERE Person_idPerson = '$id'), (SELECT idDocument FROM document WHERE typeOfDoc = '$chk1'), '$chek_val', '$isPartOfTotal',' $total_cedula', 'Unpaid');");
                    }

                    // partial total
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT price FROM document WHERE typeOfDoc = '$chk1';");
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);                             
                    $isPartOfTotal = $chek_val * $row["price"];

           } 

        ?>
        <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="step2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="memberModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" style = "background-color: #5bc0de; color: white;">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                     <h4 class="modal-title" id="memberModalLabel">Request added.</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h5>You have successfully added a new request. However, it is still tagged as unpaid.<br> This will redirect you to the invoice page.</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <?php

        //header("Refresh: 5;url=all_docRequest.php");
        mysqli_close($conn);    
    }                               
?>
```

First form html code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" name = "documentRequest" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" method="post" novalidate>

    <div class = "first">

    <div class="item form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Date of Request <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <input id="reqDate" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="reqDate" required="required" type="date" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Resident's Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <input name="person_id" id="search-box" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder ="Type in ID number..." required="required" type="text">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ln_solid"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <button id="requestDiv" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="documentRequest" >Proceed</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Second form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" name = "documentRequest1" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" method="post" novalidate>
    <div class = "second">
    <div class="item form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">ID <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <input name="a" id="search" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" value = "<?php echo $_SESSION['person_id']; ?>" required="required" type="text" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"> Document Request(s)  <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

        <input type="checkbox" name="docs[]" id="doc1" value="Certificate of Residency"/> Certificate of Residency
        <div class = "clearfix"></div>
        <div class = "col-xs-3">
            <input name="d1" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required="required" type="number">
        </div>
        <div class = "clearfix"></div>

        <input type="checkbox" name="docs[]" id="doc2" value="Barangay Clearance"/> Barangay Clearance                                                  
        <div class = "clearfix"></div>
        <div class = "col-xs-3">
            <input name="d2" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required="required" type="number"/>
        </div>

        <div class = "clearfix"></div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="docs[]" id="doc3" value="Cedula"/> Cedula                                                  
        <div class = "clearfix"></div>
        <div class = "col-xs-3">
            <input name="d3" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required="required" value = "1" type="number" readonly = "readonly"/>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ln_solid"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <button id="requestDiv1" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="documentRequest1" >Proceed</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

This is the $_SESSION code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['person_id']=isset($_POST['person_id']) ? $_POST['person_id'] :'';
?>
```

I really need your help on this one... Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: before you inserted `$_POST['person_id']` in session, check if exists in database or not.

Comment: So does the session code live in the config.php file?

Comment: where is the ID check snippet?

Comment: Your PHP code does not process the first form at all, so we have no idea how anything is passed. Why not just use a hidden input on the second form?

Comment: Also, give me 30 seconds on this website and I can erase your database completely. I'd advise scrapping the mysqli code and move to PDO with prepared statements. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php